# Find index of the first datetime element with matching date component

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have a sequence of datetime values.

```
library(lubridate)
timestamp <- seq.POSIXt(from=as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 00:00:00"),
    to=as.POSIXct("2019-01-02 23:00:00"), by= '6 hours')
> timestamp
[1] "2019-01-01 00:00:00 EET" "2019-01-01 06:00:00 EET" "2019-01-01 12:00:00 EET"
[4] "2019-01-01 18:00:00 EET" "2019-01-02 00:00:00 EET" "2019-01-02 06:00:00 EET"
[7] "2019-01-02 12:00:00 EET" "2019-01-02 18:00:00 EET"
```

I want to find the index of the first datetime element in a vector where the date component matches with input date. For example, if the date is *"2019-01-02"*, the element would be *"2019-01-02 00:00:00 EET"* and it's index is *5*.

In original data set intervals between datetimes are not constant, so the first element of the day could easily be "2019-01-02 00:00:03 EET" or "2019-01-02 00:00:10 EET", and it's important to find their indices.

So far all these lines give me NA:

```
firstDatetime = match(date("2019-01-02 12:00:00"),timestamp)
firstDatetime = match(date("2019-01-02"),timestamp)
firstDatetime = match(as_date("2019-01-02"),timestamp)
```

Comment: Would simply `timestamp == date("2019-01-02 12:00:00")` work? You can use that to index the vector, e.g. `timestamp[timestamp == date("2019-01-02 12:00:00")]`

Comment: `match(as.Date("2019-01-02"), as.Date(timestamp))` works for me unless it's your System time issue.

Comment: You can also use `which(date(timestamp) == as.POSIXct("2019-01-02"))[1]`

Comment: it did work indeed, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes of both the objects are different

```
class(as.Date("2019-01-02"))
#[1] "Date"
```

and

```
class(timestamp)
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

In all your attempts you are trying to `match` object of class `Date` with that of class `POSIXct`

Convert the `timestamp` to "date" and then `match` and it should give you the first index of match.

```
match(as.Date("2019-01-02"), as.Date(timestamp))
```